# CMSIS-DSP: Getting multiple definition of `sinTable_f32'

Tags: eclipse, arm, signal-processing, stm32, cmsis

I am trying to compile part of the CMSIS-DSP and want to use the function arm_sin_cos_f32 in file ControllerFunctions/arm_sin_cos_f32.c

Additionally the folder CommonTables is inclued. All others are excluded.

in main.c, i include #include "dsp/controller_functions.h".
In Compiler Settings, under Preprocessor (I use Eclipse), I added ARM_FAST_ALLOW_TABLES, ARM_TABLE_SIN_F32 and ARM_DSP_CONFIG_TABLES.

When I compile, i am getting the linker error
"multiple definition of `sinTable_f32'"

I dont get it why this happens.
In arm_common_tables.h sinTable_f32 is activated. The background is white. Others are gray.

/* Tables for Fast Math Sine and Cosine */
#if !defined(ARM_DSP_CONFIG_TABLES) || defined(ARM_ALL_FAST_TABLES) || defined(ARM_TABLE_SIN_F32)
extern const float32_t sinTable_f32[FAST_MATH_TABLE_SIZE + 1];
#endif /* !defined(ARM_DSP_CONFIG_TABLES) defined(ARM_ALL_FAST_TABLES) */

The sinTable_f32 is located in arm_common_tables.c.